# Did I mount this light too close to a post?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I was adding 2 new additional basement lights today, I thought I was doing a good job of mounting everything correctly and securing the wire.

[image: My Basement]

However when I finished and got someone else to look at it they pointed out that I may have mounted the lights too close to the beam.

[image: Light bulb mounted in corner, between beam, and post]

I mounted them in that position because it would still let me crawl between the posts without hitting the lights, and It was easy to work on as I could sit on the concrete pier.

[image: Wide angle of light mounted to beam]

**My question is:** *Is this light mounted too close the post? What electrical code dictates the minimum distance between the light and wood?*

I'd like to not have to not have to take them down, but if It wouldn't pass inspection I'd definitely re-do it.

Comment: I highly doubt that's a problem. But in general the issue is **heat**. Why a CFL on a new install? Put in an equivalent LED and it will use less power == generate less heat.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Just some spare bulbs I had lying around. I'm ordering some 100W equivalent LEDs. I'm mostly interested in what code has to say about the Minimum distance, or if I just shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I don't think there is any such rule. And unless you spend a ***lot*** of time crawling around your crawlspace, I wouldn't worry too much about changing the light bulbs, either. The yearly on-time is miniscule, and so is the payback from any power savings. If you can see well enough to get around, great! If you need more light for some specific task, bring a work light and take it away when you are done.

Comment: I think for confined spaces the code leans towards your lay-out; it's better to have the bulb up and out of the way so theres less chance of hitting it.

Comment: Closest I find so far: 
410.5

Luminaires (Fixtures) Near Combustible Material

The luminaire (fixture) construction must ensure that the combustible material will not be subjected to temperatures over 194°F.

Comment: @Ecnerwal -- you must have grabbed an old reference, as that section's now at 410.11

Comment: Thank you everyone, great info so far! I do actually spend a surprising amount of time down there. I should add that I'm cornered about this because we've accidently left those lights on for something like 8-9 months before. A concern about someone later on putting in an Incandescent was brought up. I'm also considering adding adding a timer, or maybe another light to indicate when I accidently leave them on.

Comment: the post throws a huge shadow when the light source is so close to the post

Comment: 1 - Timer is a good idea. 2 - I got some headlamps recently for both nighttime outside use (see and be seen) and for inside closet, etc. use - I got [these](https://www.costco.com/duracell-550-lumen-3-pack-headlamp-.product.100681259.html) at Costco but basically get whatever is on a good sale near you. (Amazon has these at more than twice what I paid!) I've seen similar at Home Depot, etc. Extremely handy - and if you set the time too short, or there is a power outage, you aren't left in the dark - but also don't tie up a hand holding your phone or a regular flashlight.

Comment: Yeah, the "someone might put in an incandescent" is what lead (or LED...) to California mandating special sockets/bulbs in new construction. Big difference in energy (= $) & heat/fire concerns (= safety) between 100W incandescent and 13W - 15W LED.

Comment: @jsotola I'd normally agree with you 100%, but I'm not seeing any nasty shadows in the big pic, so it seems there's more light from somewhere else, too.

Comment: Your crawlspace looks pretty dry.  But I would be concerned about the batt insulation under the floors.  Any kind of moisture will condense on the batts if their temperature gets below the dew point.  Once that happens, it's very hard for them to dry out completely.  Maybe this should be a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### With CFL or LED, this shouldn't be an issue

The only *plausible* Code issue with this situation is NEC 410.11 with regards to luminaires near combustible materials.  Practically speaking, though, you'll never exceed the 90°C limit the Code imposes with a normally functioning CFL or LED bulb, and even with an incandescent, the chances are rather low unless you leave the lamp burning 24/7/365.

Answer (score 1):

Code Violation? No, as stated by Ecnerwal. And, I do agree with a possible shadow problem.

Normally, lights do best when centrally located within the field of joists and on either side of any beams, to eliminate shadow problems.

But, if you're happy and your needs are addressed, then it's just fine the way you have it. Any light is better than no light. So, well done!